# Error en el flujo de ejecución Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, firebase, realtime-database

Recientemente estoy aprendiendo a usar *Android Studio* y me surgieron algunas ideas a implementar en código, el contexto del proyecto es una aplicación de materias en la cual cada alumno solo podrá ver la materia en la cual se encuentra inscrito, para eso diseñé 2 ramas en *Realtime database de Firebase* las cuales son **materias_gpo** la cual tiene como finalidad almacenar todas las materias existentes y sus respectivos datos y **alumno_materia** la cual se encarga de almacenar el **uuid** de la materia y el alumno (como si fuera el comprobante de inscripción a la materia del alumno), en el código estoy haciendo 2 consultas, una a **alumno_materia** para llenar una lista de *String* validada y otra para **materias_gpo**, que en esta ultima utilizaré la lista de *String* para demostrar solo las materias inscritas por el alumno en un *RecyclerView*.

Ahora bien, mi problema es que primero se está ejecutando la consulta a **materias_gpo** y después todo lo demás, ¿Alguien puede instruirme en este caso? Tengo mis dudas sobre si es lo mejor que lo pude hacer o si hay una mejor manera.

Código de las **Variables** y la función **onCreate** del *Activity*:

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityVerMateriasBinding
private val materiaList = mutableListOf<MateriaGrupo>()
private val idsMat = mutableListOf<String>()
private val userList = mutableListOf<Usuario>()
private lateinit var rvMateriasPreview: RecyclerView
private lateinit var materiaPreviewAdapter: MateriaPreviewAdaptador
private lateinit var usuarioLogueado: String
private lateinit var usuarioUrlImagen: String
private val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
private val usuRef = database.getReference("usuario")
private val materiasRef = database.getReference("materias_gpo")
private val alumnoMateriaRef = database.getReference("alumno_materia")
val uidd = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_materias)
    binding = ActivityVerMateriasBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    supportActionBar?.title = "Materias"

    rvMateriasPreview = binding.rvMateriasGpo
    materiaPreviewAdapter = MateriaPreviewAdaptador(materiaList)
    rvMateriasPreview.adapter = materiaPreviewAdapter

    readMaterias()

    materiaPreviewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : MateriaPreviewAdaptador.onItemClickListener{
        override fun onItemClick(id: String) {
            val intent = Intent(this@VerMateriasActivity, VerMateriaGrupoActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("uid", uidd.toString())
            intent.putExtra("id_materia", id)
            intent.putExtra("nombre_emisor", usuarioLogueado)
            intent.putExtra("urlImg", usuarioUrlImagen)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    })

    verificarUsuarioLogueado()
}
```

**Funciones** utilizadas:

```
private fun readIdsMaterias() {
    alumnoMateriaRef.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, prevChildKey: String?) {
            val newAlumnoMateria: AlumnoMateria? = dataSnapshot.getValue(AlumnoMateria::class.java)
            if (newAlumnoMateria != null) {
                if (newAlumnoMateria.id_alumno == uidd) {
                    idsMat.add(newAlumnoMateria.id_materia)
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onChildChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, prevChildKey: String?) {}
        override fun onChildRemoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {}
        override fun onChildMoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, prevChildKey: String?) {}
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
    })
}

private fun readMaterias(){
    usuRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear()
            for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                val currentUser: Usuario = snap.getValue(Usuario::class.java) as Usuario
                if (currentUser.uid == uidd) {
                    usuarioLogueado = currentUser.username
                    usuarioUrlImagen = currentUser.urlImagen
                }
                userList.add(currentUser)
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}})

    materiasRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            materiaList.clear()
            readIdsMaterias()
            for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                val currentMateria: MateriaGrupo = snap.getValue(MateriaGrupo::class.java) as MateriaGrupo
                //idsMat.forEach {
                //    if(it == currentMateria.uuid_materia)
                //        materiaList.add(currentMateria)
                //}
                for(id in idsMat){
                    if(id == currentMateria.uuid_materia)
                        materiaList.add(currentMateria)
                }
            }
            if (materiaList.size > 0 ) {
                materiaPreviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                rvMateriasPreview.smoothScrollToPosition(materiaList.size - 1)
            }
        } override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una manera sencilla de hacerlo, si están queriendo forzar un flujo de ejecución les recomiendo que implementen métodos para hacer una cadena de ejecución al momento de terminar sus procesos, en mi caso cambié el evento **onChildAdded** por un **onDataChange** y le implementé un método para mandar a llamar a mi función local.

Código resultante de la nueva función:

```
private fun readIdsMaterias() {

    alumnoMateriaRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (snap in snapshot.children) {
                val currentAlumnoMateria: AlumnoMateria = snap.getValue(AlumnoMateria::class.java) as AlumnoMateria
                if (currentAlumnoMateria.id_alumno == uidd) {
                    idsMat.add(currentAlumnoMateria.id_materia)
                }
            }
            onSuccess()
        } fun onSuccess(){
            readMaterias()
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}}) }
```

y en el **OnCreate** en vez de llamar **readMaterias()** mando a llamar a **readIdsMaterias()**:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_materias)
    binding = ActivityVerMateriasBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    supportActionBar?.title = "Materias"

    rvMateriasPreview = binding.rvMateriasGpo
    materiaPreviewAdapter = MateriaPreviewAdaptador(materiaList)
    rvMateriasPreview.adapter = materiaPreviewAdapter

    readIdsMaterias()

    materiaPreviewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : MateriaPreviewAdaptador.onItemClickListener{
        override fun onItemClick(id: String) {
            val intent = Intent(this@VerMateriasActivity, VerMateriaGrupoActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("uid", uidd.toString())
            intent.putExtra("id_materia", id)
            intent.putExtra("nombre_emisor", usuarioLogueado)
            intent.putExtra("urlImg", usuarioUrlImagen)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    })

    verificarUsuarioLogueado()
}
```